# How to run Maven surefire where each test class has its own parallel JVM?

Tags: java, maven, junit, jvm, surefire

No matter what settings I use for Maven + Surefire, I never see more than a single JVM spawned in my process manager.  I have a Windows 7 PC with 8 physical cores.  I am running the latest Maven / Surefire / JUnit and JDK8 (32-bit).

I tried decomposing all my tests into one test per test class.  (I read that JVMs are only spawned for test classes, not test methods.)  Still, I never see more than one JVM in process manager.

Ideally, I would like each test class to run a separate JVM -- 8 in parallel (one for each core / do not resuse JVMs).

What are the required Maven Surefire settings?

The following does not work for me:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>${default.test.suite}</include>
                </includes>
                <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                <forkCount>1.0C</forkCount>
                <parallel>classes</parallel>
                <threadCount>1</threadCount>
<!--
                <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
                <parallelOptimized>false</parallelOptimized>
-->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

(I tried various combinations of `reuseForks`, `forkCount`, `parallel`, `threadCount`, `useUnlimitedThreads`, and `parallelOptimized`.)

Comment: Are you using TestNG or JUnit? What's your version of the plugin, and what is the version of TestNG/JUnit that you're using?

Comment: This sentence says it all: `I am running the latest Maven / Surefire / JUnit and JDK8 (32-bit).`

Answer (score 3):

If you're using JUnit, first of all "parallel" applies only to TestNG, and so do a few other attributes, so they won't be of help / interest to you:

- http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html

Here's what works for us in a JUnit setup (doesn't work well for TestNG as just posted here: [Running test in parallel with surefire and displaying them properly with the TestNG Jenkins plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28883046/running-test-in-parallel-with-surefire-and-displaying-them-properly-with-the-tes)):

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
    <forkCount>2.5C</forkCount>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

So I think you need to increase your forkCount (with forkCount = 1.0 you won't get parallel stuff going).

For reference, here's a bit more about the small print when it comes to running tests in parallel (incl. forkCount explanation and examples):

- http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html

Comment: As of JUnit 4.7, parallel applies to JUnit as well.  See the documentation here for details: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html